# how to develop Android WLAN multiplayer game?

Tags: android, multiplayer, wifi

I'm currently trying to develop a multiplayer card game for Android.

Plan:

use java sockets for communication through WLAN.

The Game:

step 1.the splash screen(first canvas to display) asks for a nickname.

step 2.search/join available game room or create a game room.

step 3. play

questions :
1. Is this possible? The device who created a room will run as the server and anyone connecting will be client (this is all done in WLAN).

1. How can I search/broadcast the available game rooms?
2. Can anyone point me to a good tutorial? I found plenty but didn't help. This is my first time developing a game. A tutorial about any turn-based card game is very much appreciated.

thanks guys!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use the Wifi connectivity you need to take into consideration the fact that the device does not have a distinct IP address so you could only make close proximity multiplayer (on the same Wifi network), but i guess that is not the result you want to achieve.

It is possible to create what you have described. In order to have game rooms and have a real online multiplayer capabilities, you would have to use server, which all clients would communicate with and get the updated information. Now, that sounds scary but you do not need to invent the wheel and you can use an existing game sever (ex. Skiller multiplayer SDK. download from: http://dev.skiller-games.com and surprisingly, you do not have to download the server, they take care of the hosting).

Now that we have established that the connectivity in not a problem, i can tell you that the real challenge is to create an appealing a multiplayer game logic. Try to make your game quick (so users wouldn't have to wait long periods of time for each others moves) and always interest the user (when opening a new game and waiting for another user to join, the user can play with the computer?)

Hope i helped.

Comment: sir. @MrWhite Yoo

thank you for your reply.. your first paragraph got 100% accuracy.. yes i want the players to be on the same network.. my goal is to promote the game for friends being physically together(just removing the card)

so I'm currently using and engine and got the examples to work after a month of hard work... yup a month... I still haven't got the grasp on the networking issue though...

how can I establish a good communication between client and server??

as far as I noticed is that I need a class for every command and use it to broadcast to all clients. and that's it. need help